# Error when accessing ArcMap extension(add-in) methods

Tags: .net, com, arcmap, arcobjects

I have a third-party ArcMap extension (codes not available) is SomeException.
This extension implements the IExtension, IExtensionConfig, IPersistVariant and ICustomInterface interfaces
I'm calling SomeException methods from another ArcMap extension.
ICustomInterface is a custom interface.ICustomInterface is implemented inside SomeExtension class.

On a Windows 10 machine running ArcGis 10.5, the ICustomInterface methods are available from my extension and (SomeException is ICustomInterface) = true.

On a Windows 8 machine running ArcGis 10.2, ICustomInterface methods are not available from my extension and (SomeException is ICustomInterface) = false.

The IExtension, IExtensionConfig, IPersistVariant interfaces are always available.

**What could be the problem?**

Perhaps ICustomInterface is not a COM interface.
I don't know whether the SomeException extension class has the ComVisible(true) attribute or not.

**Is there any way to make all interfaces of the SomeException extension available at the OS level?**

On a Windows 8 machine running ArcGis 10.2, the ICustomInterface interface can be accessed by declaring the COM extension object as dynamic.
For example:

```
        var extClass = new UIDClass();
        extClass.Value = "{XXXXX-XXX...}";
        dynamic someExt = _application.FindExtensionByCLSID( extClass);

        someExt.SomeMethod(); //method of ICustomInterface
```

If SomeMethod has no parameters, then the call occurs correctly.
If SomeMethod has a class among its parameters, an error occurs.
For example, such a call to the method

```
 someExt.SomeMethod_2(someClass);  //method 2 of ICustomInterface
```

is the following error:

```
    System.InvalidCastException: Failed to cast object type 'System.__ComObject' to type 'someClass'.    in System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
      in System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)
   in CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject , JOB )
   in System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   in CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , JOB )
   in System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
```

**How can I call SomeMethod_2 correctly?**

Comment: "With ArcGis 10.5 ISomeInterface methods are available" "With ArcGis 10.2 ISomeInterface methods are not available", what could be the problem? Probably that ISomeInterface was added between 10.2 and 10.5. This doesn't look like an OS problem

Comment: ISomeInterface is a custom interface.ISomeInterface is implemented inside SomeExtension class

Comment: If you can't get it, it means the underling COM object doesn't implement it. InvalidCastException is typical of an error that happens when an interface is queried for another interface and the latter one is not implemented. InvalidCastException is a wrapper over native E_NOINTERFACE error code. It can also be a threading issue (you query an object for an interface on a different thread that the one which created the initial object)

Comment: But how is this possible? The interface is available on Win10 and ArcGis 10.5 (it means it's implemented the COM object). I think the interface is implemented but is not visible due to some environment properties.I know that IExtension, IExtensionConfig, IPersistVariant is COM
interfaces, but I think that ICustomInterface is not a COM interface. When I get a reference to a COM object, I see COM interfaces, but I do not see interfaces that are implemented by the class, but are not COM interfaces.

Comment: It's very well possible if it was implemented in 10.5 and not in 10.2. One can add a new interface to an object with a new version of the sofware, that's what COM allows. If it's not a COM interface, there's no way you can get it from .NET anyway. When you do `dynamic obj; obj.SomeCall()` you're not using an IUnknown interface method ("early binding") but an IDispatch interface method ("late binding"), to make it short that means you're using the name "SomeCall" to call the method, but it can be implemented by any underlying IDispatch interface.

Comment: But neither class SomeExtension nor interface ICusomExtension are elements of ArcGis. These are custom extensions and custom interfaces. Their implementation does not depend on the ArcGis version.

Comment: SomeExtension is external dll that I register as an ArcGis extension on Win 10 and Win 8.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're doing, impossible to dig further w/o some real reproducing project.